# What .NET Framework version

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

Wondering if you can compile an application using VS 2012 targeting .NET framework 2.0, or does the EXEs compiled with VS 2012 require a certain version or above of the .NET framework?

Also, is the structure of the compiled EXEs using VS 2012 the same as VS 2003, 2005, etc?

Comment: Since everything before 3.5 is (or will be in the next few months) out of even extended support, you really ought to be upgrading any current projects that "require" anything earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is not a problem. In the properties of the project, on the first tab, you can select the framework version. If you specify .NET 2.0 as the framework version, you will get an EXE that correctly works with the Microsoft .NET 2.0 framework.

Comment: Not exactly. As .NET Framework 2 SP does introduce new classes, if those are used on development machines, the developers need to pay special attention to the deployment phase. Since Microsoft stops supporting .NET 2 without SP, nowadays it should not be a critical problem any more.

Comment: It even is a little bit more complex than that. If you don't use the SP2 functionality, it still works without SP2, but it's near impossible to find out what functionality is specific to SP2.

Comment: The redbits can be found via several methods, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CatchingRedBitsDifferencesInNET20AndNET20SP1.aspx, and especially easy with NDepend as Patrick Smacchia commented.